# MikTeX not installing packages

Tags: packages, miktex

I am using WinEdt and I wanted to install the package esint.  When I compile my document to generate my pdf, it asks me if I want to install the package from online.  However, nothing ever happens, and it asks me if I want to install every single time.  What I did was I went to my MikTeX package manager to try to install it directly.  I have selected "Packages shall be installed from the Internet." Then I hit connection settings and click "Use a proxy server" but then I don't know what to enter for the address.  If someone could please help, it would be appreciated.  I am not very tech savvy so please try to limit the computer lingo/jargon as much as possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you do the installation if you don't check the "use a proxy server" box? If you are in the package manager it should be enough to just right-click the package you want installed and hit install (I get a "do you want to proceed message: 1 package will be installed" before, obviously you press "proceed" there). If that doesn't work for some reason you will get some error message. It could be though that you are trying to update at a bad time, there has just been an update; and currently some servers seem to be off line. Try again in a few hours if nothing works.

Comment: Just checked, currently I get a "The remote package repository is not online" message when using the updater. So we might just have to wait a bit until the repositories are in order again.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your help!  That was the same error message I got but I was second guessing myself on the meaning of it and was wondering if I was just messing something up.

Comment: I have the same problem. In addition, I cannot even get a list of repositories. there's probably some update going on, though it would be nice to hear from Christian to be sure...

Comment: I think yesterday when we tried to update, the repositories were just receiving the new packages and as a result of that may have rejected update requests (or something along those lines). When I tried to do an update just now it worked again (be aware though, that according to the MikTeX website not all repositories are up to date at this time, so you might want to give it another few hours).

Comment: Thanks everyone.  It's funny how wanting to put a 1/4 cm bar through an integral symbol can result in such a MikTeX fiasco :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by waiting until the MikTeX repository mirrors were up and running again.

Comment: I would condone, but it could be helpful to those with similar problems in the future

Comment: So are they not up and running still? I am trying it now and nothing is working.